# Undo Delete From WWV_FLOW_FILES

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Is there a way to undo "delete from WWV_FLOW_FILES" in Oracle Apex version 4.2?

I have tried

```
        FLASHBACK TABLE WWV_FLOW_FILES
        TO TIMESTAMP (SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' hour);
```

This code yields "ORA-01702: a view is not appropriate here"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since that's not a table, getting such an error is normal. Try to use

```
select * 
  from WWV_FLOW_FILES 
 as of timestamp systimestamp - interval '1' hour
```

instead.

*Against the case of raising `ORA-01702` error, consider granting select privilege to public for this public synonym so that you can query from any schema, including your current one.*

*P.S. First of all, your schema should have Flashback Query privilege. For this aim, Grant FLASHBACK and SELECT privileges on specific objects to be accessed during queries, or grant the FLASHBACK ANY TABLE privilege to allow queries on all tables*.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that and got "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges" I have reached out to the party responsible for privileges.  Is this possible without privilege escalation?

Comment: @BillyBarbarIan that's a public synonym, and select privilege should be granted to public so that you can query from any schema, including your current one. i.e. it seems you need to consult your DBA.

Comment: You need the `SELECT` privilege as well as either `FLASHBACK` on the appropriate objects or the `FLASHBACK ANY TABLE` system privilege.

Comment: @eaolson yes, we need such FLASHBACK privileges basically, thanks.